# The ctrl button on my mac isn't working

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an alternative way to shutdown servers when i'm using terminal?
 or do I have to get it fixed. I'm a student

Comment: Shut down servers....  From the terminal... Are you sure that this is an OS X question?  What kind of server?

Comment: a rails server, i want to use virtual box and vagrant so i can use ubuntu on my mac but my ctrl button doesn't work, so i can't use ctrl + c

Comment: `vagrant down`...  No need for a control key.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sudo rights then add following alias to your .bashrc

```
alias poweroff='sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now'
```

Then you only need to type `poweroff` in your terminal and type in the administrator password

Answer (score 0):

just change in the machine menu
Input/keyboard/Keyboard settings/
and in the tab
Input/Virtual Machine/

The "Host Key Combination" to Ctrl+Alt instead of Right Ctrl. That will solve it.